# What is the probability of this happening?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have 8 chits of paper. '**Yes**' is written on 4 chits and '**No**' is written on 4 chits. These chits are folded and jumbled. So if i pick a chit, i won't know what's written inside it unless i open it.

This is the procedure for picking:

1. I will jumble the chits and pick one at random.
2. After opening and writing down the content of the chit, i will fold
   it, put it back into the bunch of chits and jumble it again.

So these are my Questions:

If i pick 7 times (that is... i pick a chit, read it, put it back and jumble it):

1. How many different combinations are there?
2. What is the probability that i get 5 '**Yes**'es and 2 '**No**'s *or* 2 '**Yes**'es and 5 '**No**'s.

And my final question:

If i repeat this whole process from the beginning 4 times (that is.... picking 7 times and getting a combination of '**Yes**'es and '**No**'s.):

1. How many different combinations exist?
2. What is the probability of getting 5 '**Yes**'es and 2 '**No**'s 4 times in a row.

Comment: Did you mean how many different sequences are there?  Also, what have you attempted and where are you stuck?

Comment: Hint : Every chit can have either "yes" or "no", i.e. 2 possibilities. So no. of combinations on 7 chits = 2*2*... Also, have you heard about probability of a binomial distribution?

Answer (score 1):

You have a sequence of $7$ draws. Because you put back the chit after each draw, we have two equally probable options **Y** and **N** for each draw (like we would have with $7$ (fair) coin tosses).

So we have $2^7 =128$ many equiprobable sequences of outcomes.

How many sequences are the with 5 **Y** and 2 **N**? We have $7$ ways to pick the first occurrence of **N**, and $6$ for the second, but we can interchange each choice (first **N** at position $i$ and the second at position $j$ is the same sequence as when we would pick the first **N** at position $j$ and the second at $i$) and so we have $21 = \frac{6 \times 7}{2}$ such sequences. So the first probability is $\frac{21}{128}$.

The chance that this will happen 4 times in a row, is just that probability to the power $4$ by the product rule for independent events. So $$\left(\frac{21}{128}\right)^4 = 0.0007244981825351715$$